# Compiling SBCL from source on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, build, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I need to compile SBCL from source and enable threading on my Mac OS X MacBook.

I've done the following:

1. Downloaded sbcl-1.0.29.54.rc1 and unzipped it to the root of my hard drive (I could put it somewhere else if that would be better).
2. Invoked

   ```
   sh make.sh
   ```

It does a lot of stuff (it doesn't fail immediately), but then the following failure occurs:

```
make: *** [backtrace.o] Error 1
```

I can't really tell what the problem is from the preceding output:

```
; /sbcl-1.0.29.54.rc1/obj/from-host/src/compiler/generic/genesis.lisp-obj-tmp written
; compilation finished in 0:00:02.281
STYLE-WARNING: redefining FOP-MAYBE-COLD-LOAD in DEFUN
T
* 
beginning GENESIS, creating headers in "src/runtime/genesis"
NIL
* 
real    1m24.729s
user    1m17.343s
sys 0m5.793s
//entering make-target-1.sh
//building runtime system and symbol table file
rm -f *.[do] sbcl sbcl.nm sbcl.h core *.tmp 
echo '#include "genesis/config.h"' >sbcl.h
echo '#include "genesis/constants.h"' >>sbcl.h
In file included from darwin-os.c:21:
/usr/include/ucontext.h:42:2: error: #error ucontext routines are deprecated, 
      and require _XOPEN_SOURCE to be defined
gcc -g -Wall -O2 -fdollars-in-identifiers -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -I. -no-cpp-precomp  -c -o alloc.o alloc.c
In file included from alloc.c:21:
runtime.h: In function 'CONS':
runtime.h:151: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
runtime.h: In function 'SYMBOL':
runtime.h:157: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
runtime.h: In function 'FDEFN':
runtime.h:163: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
gcc -g -Wall -O2 -fdollars-in-identifiers -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -I. -no-cpp-precomp  -c -o backtrace.o backtrace.c
In file included from backtrace.c:19:
runtime.h: In function 'CONS':
runtime.h:151: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
runtime.h: In function 'SYMBOL':
runtime.h:157: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
runtime.h: In function 'FDEFN':
runtime.h:163: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
/var/folders/T2/T2z5uzvpHnmC3o+vJVluoU+++TI/-Tmp-//ccEobrpp.s:851:suffix or operands invalid for `mov'
make: *** [backtrace.o] Error 1
```

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is a patch located [at this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/sbcl/+bug/393845) . Try applying it and rebuilding cleanly (make clean && ...) then see if the problem goes away.

Comment: and reason you're compiling an old sbcl, though? that patch is in newer versions.

Answer (score 2):

That version is pretty old. SBCL is up to 1.0.44. 1.0.44 builds fine on Mac OS X.